# compile and link CxImage static lib in VC++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, linker, static-libraries, linker-errors

I tried to use [CxImage](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/cximage.aspx) in my project VC++, however I use a walkthrough for create static libs and link with a project in VC++ 2010.

Everything looks fine when I generate the project that link the `cximage.lib`, but for some reason when I use certain functions the compiler threw me a `LINK:2001 unresolved external symbol`.

This is the first time I work with visual static libraries, if someone have the solution or a suggestion for this I would be grateful.

here is my code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CxImage imag;
    imag.Save((const TCHAR *)"hola.bmp",CXIMAGE_FORMAT_BMP);
    return 0;
}
```

and there it is, `CxImage` is recognized by the compiler but some functions on the linker not. In this case the function `Save`, if I used other functions and work, the generation is successful.  I searched over the net and find that I could by not including a library but I include it.

The link error is the next:

```
pruebaCxImage.obj : error LNK2001: símbolo externo "public: bool __thiscall CxImage::Save(wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?Save@CxImage@@QAE_NPB_WI@Z) sin resolver
```

for more information this is the command's of my linker in the project:

```
/OUT:"C:\Documents and Settings\diego\Mis documentos\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\pruebaCxImage\Release\pruebaCxImage.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Release\pruebaCxImage.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Documents and Settings\diego\Mis documentos\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\pruebaCxImage\Release\pruebaCxImage.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib "..\..\..\..\..\escritorio\cximage701_full\cximage\release\cximage.lib"
```

Comment: What in the world is CxImage?

Comment: @Cody: See the link I added to the question. Never mind: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/cximage.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You build the exe with UNICODE/_UNICODE defined, since TCHAR expands to wchar_t (see the linker error), so my guess is that you built the lib without defining UNICODE/_UNICODE **or** didn't add the lib output directory to the list of lib input directories in the exe properties.

Comment: thanks @Johann i try your suggestion and the function is recognized but in the next step i have so many link errors and i fix them :D very very thanks you save me XD

Comment: cxImage has a Unicode_Debug and Unicode_Release configuration. I linked with those libraries and it worked! Thanks.